# HTML 5 Datalist Option

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, html-datalist

How can I use data from database to place it in a datalist for HTML5

for example

```
<input list="browsers">

<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

How can I retrieve options from database? Instead of placing it manually. I'm using asp.net C#

Comment: do a search on `asp:listbox` you will find many examples.

Comment: Invalid close - `asp:ListBox` <> _HTML5 datalist_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I already solve my problem by using this codes.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bindProducts();
}

private void bindProducts()
{
    using (systemDbEntities context = new systemDbEntities())
    {
        var q = from c in context.Products select new { c.ProductId, c.Name };
        foreach (var item in q)
        {
            lstProducts.InnerHtml += "<option value='" + item.Name + "'>";
        }
    }
}
```

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxSearch" runat="server" placeholder="Search"  
             list="lstProducts"></asp:TextBox>
<datalist id="lstProducts" runat="server"></datalist>
```

Thank you guys! :)